# Laravel 5.* - first item on the list doesn't show the <form> tag

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

All of my items/index pages have this bug where the first item of the loop doesn't have the form tag.

```
@foreach($items as $item)
                    
    <tr class="table-borderless">
        <td>
            <form method="POST" action="/itemlist/{{ $item->id }}/add-to-build">
                <center>
                    @csrf
                                    
                    // snipped necessary input:hiddens here

                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark btn-sm">Add</button>      
                </center>
            </form>
        </td>
//snipped other tds

@endforeach
```

Consecutive items have the form tag which is weird

what my $items dumps ( called by Item::get() )

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1501 ▼
  #items: array:4 [▼
    0 => App\itemList {#1498 ▶}
    1 => App\itemList {#1497 ▶}
    2 => App\itemList {#1495 ▶}
    3 => App\itemList {#1494 ▶}
  ]
}
```

First item code on dev console (no form)
[image]

Succeeding items
[image]

EDIT: For some odd reason, adding a blank form made it work. Not sure why, still need to improve on something

```
@foreach($mobos as $mobo)
                    
    <tr style="vertical-align: middle;">
        <td> <form ></form> 
            <form method="POST" action="/itemlist/{{ $item->id }}/add-to-build" enctype="multipart/form-data"> @csrf
```

Comment: "show the form tag"? its not in the source that is returned?

Comment: Do you mean the variable breaks your html?

Comment: @MaartenVeerman no, just for the first item. second, third, etc item shows the form though

Comment: Could you show the structure of the `$items` array together with that first item?

Comment: what's the problem here actually?? you want the form in the first row only?? or your form is not showing for the first row but showing for the other rows??

Comment: @zahidhasanemon no, form doesnt show on the first. all others are showing though

Comment: @MaartenVeerman added on main question

Comment: do you set any condition anywhere??

Comment: What happens when you replace everything between the `@foreach` lines by a simple text string. Does that show 4 lines than?

Comment: @zahidhasanemon none, even to consider there is, the first item doesnt get triggered for a form

Comment: @MaartenVeerman yes i can display the name on the side of the button (though I excluded it from the sample above)

Comment: Could you show the complete output of the first item, to understand what you mean with "form does not show"

Comment: @MaartenVeerman added

Comment: The php code you show and output do not match 100%. For example, I see extra css class names in the output. Is there any JavaScript that is being run to loop over the table contents and maybe modifies the content?

Comment: @MaartenVeerman yes, that are datatables.js classes for sorting